# How to access Private properties in php or even can i?

Tags: php, private

I have a simple example of code in which i would like to set the private property $ttlBal.

```
<$php
$balance = new Customer;
$greeting = fopen("greeting.txt", "r");
while(!feof($greeting)){
    echo fgets($greeting) . "<br>";
}
fclose($greeting);
$balance->acctBal = 12;
$balance->deposits = 12;
$balance->fdr = 12;


$balance->findAvail($balance->acctBal, $balance->deposits, $balance->ttlBal);
class Customer{
    public $acctBal; 
    public $deposits;
    private $acctAvail;
    private $ttlBal;
    public $fdr;

    public function findAvail($bal, $dep, $ttlBal){
        echo $this->ttlBal = $bal - $dep;
    }
}
?>
```

This brings about an error that I cannot access the private property $ttlBal. In which way can I access this.

Comment: private properties are only available to functions inside the class create a get function

Answer (score 6):

You should add a public setter method to your class:

```
class Foo {
    private $var;

    public function setVar($value) {
        $this->var = $value;
    }
}
```

Also in many cases `protected` is what you want if you use `private`. If you just want to hide the variable from public access, use `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

Youe error is here `$balance->ttlBal`

Either you will make the property `public` or you would implement `get()` and `set()` methods for it in `Customer` class.

As an example

```
public function get_ttlBal()
{
    return $this->ttlBal;
}
```

and then you can call

```
$balance->findAvail($balance->acctBal, $balance->deposits, $balance->get_ttlBal());
```

Answer (score 1):

To access private properties, previously set by setter function,  you should write and use getter method.

```
public function getVar() {
    return $this->_var;
}
```